# Regular expression in java to allow only alphanumeric input data

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric

I need the regex expression which would accept only alphanumeric data.

Say for eg: ABC12DG - should allow this

if input data is 123000 - should not allow as it is only numeric.

I have tried this

say a is a string which contains the input data

then a.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$") this allows both the first and second input as above

I only want it to allow the alphanumeric input , not just numeric or alphabets
How to do that

Answer (score 4):

Use negative lookahead or alternation operator.

```
a.matches("^(?![A-Za-z]+$)(?!\\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

- `(?![A-Za-z]+$)` asserts that the match won't contain only alphabets.
- `(?!\\d+$)` asserts that the match won't contain only digits.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Matches one or more alphanumeric characters.

or

```
a.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:[a-zA-Z]\\d|\\d[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

Comment: what is this expression.. can u explain pls

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Regex for your text:

```
    String reg = "\\p{Alpha}+\\d+";
    String str1 = "It &* is %$ now OK 2015";
    String str2 = "ItisnowOK2015";
    String str3 = "888";
    String str4 = "aaa";
    System.out.println("str1 = "+str1.matches(reg));
    System.out.println("str2 = "+str2.matches(reg));
    System.out.println("str3 = "+str3.matches(reg));
    System.out.println("str4 = "+str4.matches(reg));
```

And is the result:

```
str1 = false
str2 = true
str3 = false
str4 = false
```

Comment: can you give it in this way like a-z A-Z , that would be good

Comment: not this way.. am looking for regex which includes this kind of expression a-zA-Z 0-9 instead of Alnum

Comment: Yourself said that: Regular expression in java to allow only alphanumeric input data. Then this regex just do what you asked

Comment: @BahramdunAdil your regex should also allow `aaa` and `888` . But this is not op expects..

Comment: I have already wrote a test code in the answer, did you see OR NOT

Comment: `I only want it to allow the alphanumeric input , not just numeric or alphabets`, your regex returns true for `888`

Comment: can anyone give me a perfect solution please